# How to stop ggplot2 facet duplicating variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

So I am using ggplot2 to make a nice little plot with my data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Background = factor(c("Input", "H3", "Overlap","Input", "H3", "Overlap"), levels=c("Input", "H3", "Overlap")), 
            Condition = factor(c("control", "control", "control","treatment", "treatment", "treatment")),
            Count = c(10, 9, 5, 8, 7, 6))

barplot = ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Condition, y=Count, fill=Background)) +
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge()) +
    facet_grid(. ~ Condition)
```

And I want to separate "control" from "treatment". I sort of achieve that but both are still represented in the individual panels:

[image]

How to avoid this?

Cheers.

Comment: add `scale="free"` to `facet_grid`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tyler's comment is one solution.  But why plot the facet variable as the x variable?  Instead, I would use Background as your x.

```
barplot = ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Background, y=Count, fill=Background)) +   
  geom_bar(position='dodge') + 
  facet_grid(.~Condition)
```

Comment: ...or why facet at all: `ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Background, y=Count, fill=Condition)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge())`.

Comment: @Just this use of treatment and control struck me as odd too.  Using Justin's method you can kill the legend.  I also think joran's solution makes sense.

Comment: @Justin: it had to be something simple. It did not occur to me to use that variation (x=Background) because without faceting it does not make the variable separation I need. Cheers.

Comment: @joran, there is a very good reason to do faceting (and my question is about faceting) as it visually highlights the point being made in this graph. The plotting you suggest I can do but it only makes the data - for my particular goal - look more unintelligible.

Comment: @krespim I am, in fact, perfectlywell aware of all that. Which is why I wrote a comment and not an answer. These Q's serve a much bigger purpose than your narrow circumstances, so it can often be useful to have some other perspectives and options contained in them. Try to be more open to what could potentially be useful to someone landing on this page via Google.